# How can I create nodes in Memgraph directly from Python?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have an application that uses Memgraph. At the moment, queries are written using Cypher. I'd like to move them to Python. What would be the equivalent of Cypher clauses `CREATE` (e.g.`CREATE (:City {name: 'London'});`)  and `MERGE` (e.g. `MERGE (:City {name: 'Dublin'});`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to install [GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy). GQLAlchemy is a standalone Object Grap Mapper (OGM) for Python.

For creating nodes, use the method `node()` after `create()`:

```
from gqlalchemy import Create

query = Create().node(labels="City", name="London").execute()
```

When you use the `merge()` method instead of `create()`, the node won't be created if it already exists, it will only be updated if the properties don't match:

```
from gqlalchemy import Merge

query = Merge().node(labels="City", name="Dublin").execute()
```